# Why does PFQuery only return one object from a class?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to query a class called UserPhoto. It has many photos with a field reference to user.
However, when I find all objects in background, it only returns one.

```
// get currentUserId
NSString *userId = [self.userIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

PFQuery *photoQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
[photoQuery includeKey:@"user"];

[photoQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Objects: %@", objects);

    for (PFObject *photo in objects) {

        NSLog(@"%@, %@", [photo objectForKey:@"user"], userId);

        if ([[[photo objectForKey:@"user"] objectId] isEqualToString:userId]) {

            // turn that photo into ns data
            UIImage *profilePicture = [UIImage imageWithData:[[photo objectForKey:@"imageFile"] getData]];
            cell.imageArea.image = profilePicture;
            cell.nameLabel.text = [[photo objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];

        }
    }
}];
```

Edit: This is in the tableView:cellForAtIndexPath:

I know its bad but I'm testing it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a problem with Access Control Lists (ACL).

Where I uploaded the photos to the UserPhoto class, I also made sure that the photo is uploaded receives a public read access like this:

```
         userPhoto.ACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
        [userPhoto.ACL setPublicReadAccess:TRUE];
```

If you look in the data browser in the ACL section, it might be similar to this:

```
 {"*":{"read":true},"fTSp8k4pLQ":{"write":true,"read":true}}
```

I have the user given itself write and read access but also gave public access with the wild card.